# Using ajax to check price based on selected option

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am trying  to change the price based on the  option a user choose. I am getting the price and sizes from the database.  Is they a way to use ajax to change the price base on the bsize that user choose from the drop down options. In my database I have

Table name: size

```
  Sid       bsize.  Sprice  
  1         12         200  
  2         14         250  
  3         16         400
```

```
<div class="soat_r">
    <form id="add2cart" name="cart" method="Post" action="<?php fetchdir($bpages); ?>cart.php">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td width="160">Price:</td>
                <td name="price"></td><!-- the price will go here and will change depend on the bsize the choose -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td for="size" width="160">size*:</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="size" class="small" id ="size">
                    <!-- I will echo out the bsize here and it will be in a drop down <option> -->
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>   
            <tr>

            </tr>   
            <tr>
                <td>Quantity</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Qty" value="1" style="width: 20px; text-align: right" /></td>
            </tr>       
        </table>    
        <div class="cleaner h20"></div>

        <input type="hidden" name="pid" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>" />
        <input type="Submit" class="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add to shopping cart"/>
    </form>             
</div>
```

They product is listing in a differed t table so I have 1 Adidas blue 2. addias white  3. addidias green then on a different table I have the price... The price for addidas change depending on the size... Thats why I have a  table for size and price... On the cart page am posting the name, the size the choose and the price(which depends on the size)... Let's say you go on the blue addias page. You choose the size, I want it to tell you the price for that size on the price tr... Without you having to add to the cart to find out... I tried to do this but I am out of ideas and I really will be greatful if someone can show me a few codes for this... Thanks

Comment: It is not just your table, you question is also not very clear.

Comment: Sorry about my English I have edit it and hopefully it make sense

Comment: yea, you can get the price through ajax and then display it to the user. maybe you should start by trying to make an ajax request?

Comment: I did this before using jquery and assigning the price in the value but I found out someone could change the value and submit the price as whatever price they feel obvious I don't want this to happen and the best way to prevent this is getting the price and size from the database and then using ajax to change the price based on the size the user choose.

Comment: use the product id when submitting, then on the serverside you look up the price for the product, just like in real life with scanning a barcode ;)

Comment: @rednaw http://jsfiddle.net/J4rXX/5/ look at here and see an idea of what i want to do i cant use this because of javascript injection. But the idea is i want the price to change before the user submit not for them to submit and then find out the price

Comment: yes you CAN use that. What's the problem if someone would change the values in javascript? It's client sided. You just need to make sure you work with product Id's and not sending over prices from the client... that would be really unsecure, letting the client choose what price he wants to pay...

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

**if you use jQuery:**

```
$('#size').change(function() {
    $.post("get_price_by_bsize.php", "bsize="+$("#size").val())
        $("#price_td").html(data);
    });
});
```

on the **get_price_by_bsize.php** just run a query:

```
SELECT Sprice from size WHERE bsize={$_POST['bsize']}
```

and print the price. Don't forget to assign an id to price `<td>`.

**Without jQuery** , same principal, but with [xmlhttprequest](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) and [onclick](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp)